# What heap ordering property will be used, if I push list elements inside a heap?

Tags: python, heap

Suppose I create a heap and push some list elements inside the heap as follows:

```python
from heapq import heapify,heappop,heappush
pq = []
heapify(pq)
heappush(pq,[4,0,1])
heappush(pq,[7,1,3])
heappush(pq,[2,4,2])
```

How will the `heappop()` operation return values?
In my case, I want the first element of the list to be used in min heap ordering property. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want the first element of the list to be used in min heap ordering property.

That is what will happen. The items you pass as argument in `heappush` will be compared. In Python, lists are compared by their first member, and if that is a tie, by their second member, ...etc. So for example `[2,4,2]` is less than `[2,8,1]`. This is a behaviour that is tied to lists and tuples, and is not specific for `heapq`, but `heapq` relies on it.

In your example, when you continue to pop the elements from the heap, like this:

```
while pq:
    print(heappop(pq))
```

You'll get them output in sorted order:

```
[2, 4, 2]
[4, 0, 1]
[7, 1, 3]
```

#### Remark

As you don't want elements on the heap to be *mutated* (as that could break there proper heap order), you should better use *tuples* and not *lists*:

```
heappush(pq, (4,0,1))
heappush(pq, (7,1,3))
heappush(pq, (2,4,2))
```